# Strange binary operation: $a\oplus b = (a-b)||(a+b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

> Motivation: A facebook post had a bunch of these as an 'intelligence' test, so I thought I would think about what this operation is. But I haven't done this Math in years!

I have an operation $\oplus$ defined by $a\oplus b = (a-b)||(a+b)$ where $||$ is the [concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation_%28mathematics%29) operation.

e.g.

$$5\oplus1=(5-1)||(5+1)=4|| 6 = 46$$
$$9\oplus3=(9-3)||(9+3)=6|| 12 = 612$$

What is this? What does it mean? So I have $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ here. Can someone tell me what sort of morphism this is? Or explain what this means mathematically? It is a binary operation I can see, but I am not sure what to call the mapping.

Let's look for identity: $5\oplus x=x\oplus 5=5$, means that $5\oplus x=(5-x)||(5+x)=5$
and associativity I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what the "intelligence" test was asking? Surely it wasn't as open ended as you make it seem?

Comment: @Casteels It was just one of those little 'what is the pattern' intelligence tests, and left 10 little sums(with this not real addition)

Comment: Since the influence of signs (esp. of the second "summand") is unspecified, you rather have $f\colon \mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Very true, apologies

Comment: And to somewhat answer your question: Methematically, this is ... nothing remarkable (esp., as it depends on the decimal system).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But what is it? Is it a monoid? A semi-group? A group?

Comment: @GitGud Thank you so much for that binary operation being defined

Comment: Why the downvote though, that is sad for an old man like me to be rejected immediately, but I guess what can you do

Comment: @terry The down vote came when the question was still very unclear. In any case these random IQ test things aren't usually welcome here. As the question is right now, I think the facebook vibe has been abandoned and the question is OK.

Comment: By the way, you might want to edit your question to include Hagen's correction above. Also note that you should use $\oplus$ instead of $f$, because in fact $f=\oplus$.

Comment: @jibounet No it isn't, the $a-b$ digits sit to the left of the $a+b$ digits.

Comment: @Autolatry : Ah ok ! Sorry, I did not understand it that way !

Answer (score 1):

It isn't even a [Magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) since it isn't defined for all pairs $a,b\in\Bbb N$. If $a\oplus b$ is defined then $b\oplus a$ is not defined.

If you redefine the operation so that $a\oplus b=((|a-b|)\|(a+b))$ it would be a magma but not associative: $1\oplus (2\oplus 3)=1\oplus15=1416$ but $(1\oplus 2)\oplus 3=13\oplus3=1016$.

Comment: I'd say that $b\oplus a = -(a\oplus b)$? For instance $1\oplus 2 = (-1)||3=-13$.

Comment: @Myself: but how to define $a\oplus (-1)$ then..?

Comment: $5\oplus (-1) = 6||4=64$ and $1\oplus(-5)=6||(-4)=6-4=2$? It looks totally useless but if the || operator is meant to treat numbers as strings, concatenate them and interpret the result as mathematics there is no real objection against negative numbers.

Comment: But you are right of course that it is most definitely not a function $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ as the OP suggests.